# How to store values of x in a tuple after performing a loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, tuples

So I am a beginner in python and was given an exercise to find the mean of 6 randomly generated 6-digit numbers. I applied a logic that I can run it through a while loop and get 6 random variables and then get them in a tuple and then find its mean. but I cant get them in a tuple. I don't know what is wrong. PLS HELP!!

and the error its giving me is given after the code that I wrote

```
    import random as r
import statistics as s
i=1
tup=()
while i<=6:
    x=r.randrange(100000,999999,500)
    tup()==(tup,x)
    i=i+1
    print(x)
    y=s.mean(tup())
    print(y)
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/personal/python programs/siuuu.py", line 85, in <module>
    tup()==(tup,x)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: Tuples are immutable, you can't add to them. Use a list.

Comment: What is `tup()==(tup,x)` supposed to mean? `tup` is a tuple, not a function, you can't call it. `==` is comparison, but you're not using the result of the comparison. I suspect you meant `tup = tup + (x,)` to make a larger tuple.

Answer (score 0):

tuples aren't editable once created. Use a list instead.

```
import random as r
import statistics as s
i=1
my_numbers=[]
while i<=6:
    x=r.randrange(100000,999999,500)
    my_numbers.append(x)
    i=i+1
    print(x)

y=s.mean(my_numbers)
print(f"My average is {y}")
```

Comment: use s.fmean as it is faster than s.mean

Answer (score 0):

You are trying use tuples like list. I suggest you use something like this:

```
import random as r
import statistics as s

i = 1
my_list = []
while i<=6:
    x=r.randrange(100000,999999,500)
    my_list.append(x)
    print(x)
    y=s.mean(my_list)
    print(y)
    i += 1
```

If you want, the list can be tuple-converted after process then it will be immutable.

```
my_tuple = tuple(my_list)
```

If you want the result only at the end of the process:

```
import random as r
import statistics as s
y = s.mean((r.randrange(100000, 999999, 500) for i in range(0,6)))
print(y)
```

Or

```
import random as r
import statistics as s

i = 1
my_list = []

while i<=6:
    x=r.randrange(100000,999999,500)
    my_list.append(x)
    print(x)
    i += 1

my_tuple = tuple(my_list)
y=s.mean(my_tuple)
print(y)
```

Hope this helps you.